Systemd service exits immediately (error 203) but runs fine standalone?
I wrote a small application (ELF binary) that listens for TCP/IP connections and it works fine when I run it from the command line but when I use systemd it errors with code 203.
Here is my service file:
[Unit]
Description=Remote Input Service Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/sofakng/risd/risd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Here is the status from systemd when I try to start it:
× risd.service - Remote Input Service Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/risd.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-09-21 22:06:38 EDT; 2min 24s ago
   Duration: 1ms
    Process: 18247 ExecStart=/home/sofakng/risd/risd (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 18247 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 532us

Sep 21 22:06:38 bazzite systemd[1]: Started risd.service - Remote Input Service Daemon.
Sep 21 22:06:38 bazzite systemd[1]: risd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 21 22:06:38 bazzite systemd[1]: risd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

However, when I run the binary from the command line it works perfectly.  I can run it as myself or as root and it works fine both ways.  I've checked permissions on the file (a+x) and I'm confused why it's not working.

203/EXEC means that systemd couldn't launch your process.
You're right to check chmod a+x.  That's the usual culprit.
The second most-common culprit is an incorrect path.  Check the spelling of /home/sofakng/risd/risd.
If you've defined WorkingDirectory=, and the directory doesn't exist, systemd will also 203/EXEC.
Assuming you've done all of that, then the difference is probably in your shell.  Environment variables like $LD_LIBRARY_PATH could be defined in your /etc/bash.bashrc or /etc/profile, and those would not be picked up by the systemd environment.  LD_LIBRARY_PATH specifically could cause your process to fail to start because missing libraries or symbols will trigger 203/EXEC.  A solution to that could be to:
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /home/sofakng/risd/risd

or
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sofaking/risd/risd

If $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is defined in /home/sofakng/.bashrc, then you may need to:
User=sofakng
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /home/sofakng/risd/risd


Thanks!  The only solution that worked was using bash to launch the executable.  However, it seems to be starting too early because it fails on boot but I can start it manually afterwards.  I've added After=network.target but that doesn't seem to be enough.  My service interacts with /dev/uinput so maybe I need to wait for something else to start?

A little in-elegant, but if you don't know what your program depends on, you could always ExecStartPre=sleep 5

user systemctl status and browse the various *.target, *.mount, and *.device units.  Use After= on one (or more) of those units.  network.target was a good start.

Wild guess: this is a traditional daemon that runs in the background.
When you start it from systemd, you need to pass a flag that tells it to remain in the foreground.

I think Type=forking would be the easiest solution for a traditional daemon that runs in the background.  But even then, the process would run and exit immediately.  The question shows 203/EXEC which means the process never even starts.

Thanks for the reply but my service doesn't fork.  It stays running in the foreground and doesn't require any flags to be passed, etc.
